# Autocomplete - work with a dataset, or slave the server

Tags: algorithm, web-applications

I am working on an autocomplete feature and now I am pretty not sure about the strategy I am going to go with.

**I am not asking for any suggestion about a 3rd party solution, there's a reason why I need to implement this myself**

I already have a backend service that gives me the results.
My question is: which one is a more suitable approach:

1. Before initializing the component - load the data and work with it
2. Every time the user inputs, I call the server with the matching results.

**I have no info about the data size, I cannot assume anything about it**

I tend to prefer the second option. But, isn't it an overkill? Is calling the server for each input is not too expensive to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second option will be best if

- The data set is extremely large.
- Or, if you have a reason to keep the whole data set private

First option will be easier to implement and hence preferable if the above two factors don't apply.